# How to use mcms 2002 with sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, mcms-2000

I have an old version of Microsoft Content Management System (MCMS-2002).  I have a request to update our database server from sql2005 to sql2008.  I can migrate the cms database just fine from 2005 to 2008, and I can set the compatibility mode to 2005.

However, when I use the Database Configuration Application (from MCMS) to point at the sql2008 server I get the following error:

> Unable to use selected SQL Server. The
>   server must be SQL Server 2000 Service
>   Pack 2 or better.

I find it ironic, but frustrating, that it doesn't recognize the newer version of sql server.  I have found some indications that MCMS queries the database for its version number but only accepts a single digit version number.

So SQL2000 -> version 8
SQL2005 -> version 9
SQL2008 -> version 10 : but MCMS only gets Version 1 and thinks it is a VERY old version.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to the MCMS' J# version problem where setup is asking for version 3.0 which does not even exist.

I hope somebody does find a workaround as we are about the face the same problem soon.